# how to create workspace in oracle XE

Tags: ora-08177

how to create workspace in oracle XE

Comment: seems like google should be able to answer that...

Answer (score 1):

Try to login at http://localhost:8080/apex/apex_admin , put your credentials there and you will be able to access the web page to create a workspace.

Take into account that the default username is ADMIN, and the password is the one you entered when you installed the software. The system will ask you to change it again.